# I'm getting stuck while trying to make a calculator using html and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

For a school project I have to make a calculator using html and Javascript. There should be three input boxes, one to enter a first number, one to enter a second number and a third one to guess the right answer. Below there should be a button to calculate.

The calculator has to be able to do: +, -, :, *, modulo

The third box should be used to type a self guessed answer, then after the calculation, there has to be a pop up which says wrong answer, or right answer.

But right now I'm getting stuck at this point, I created all the input boxes and the calculator is able to add numbers. But I just don't know how to do the rest. Can someone please help me out with this?

Here is the code I have right now:
(There are a few Dutch words in there. "Getal" means: Digit. "Uitkomst" means: Answer "berekenSom" means: Calculate)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Calculator</title>
      <style>
         h3 {
            color: green;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <pre>
         <h2>Javascript Calculator</h2>
         Insert first number:   <input type="number" id="getal_1">

         Insert second number:  <input type="number" id="getal_2">
        
         My own calculation:    <input type="number" id="getal_3">

         <h3 id="uitkomst" >The answer is:</h3>

         <button id="button">Calculate</button>
      </pre>
   </body>
</html>
<script>
   document.getElementById("button").onclick = berekenSom;
   var uitkomst = document.getElementById("uitkomst");
   
   
   function berekenSom() {
      var getal1 = document.getElementById("getal_1").value;
      
      var getal2 = document.getElementById("getal_2").value;


      var som = parseFloat(getal1) + parseFloat(getal2);

      uitkomst.style.color = "red";

      uitkomst.innerHTML = "The calculation " + getal1 + " + " + getal2 + " = " + som;
   }
</script>
```

I would appreciate it a lot if someone could help me with this, because I'm kinda stuck at the moment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well you're calculating the value and storing it as `som`, correct? The next step is simply to get the text from the third input (just as you did with `var getal1` and `var getal2`), and do an `if` statement. `if (parseFloat(input3value) == som)  { alert("Correct!"); } else { alert("Incorrect!"); }` - Check out the basics of [JavaScript If...Else statements](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp) for more information.

Comment: Use a `<select>` that lets you choose the operation. Then you can write a `switch()` statement that performs the appropriate calculation depending on which operation they selected.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I did the "+" functionality for you. Since it was a school project, I'm going to try to not do the entire thing for you. If you need more help, just ask :)

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick = berekenSom;
var uitkomst = document.getElementById("uitkomst");


function berekenSom() {
  var getal1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("getal_1").value); 
  var getal2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("getal_2").value);
  var getal3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("getal_3").value);
  
  var op = document.getElementById("operation")
  var select = op.options[op.selectedIndex].value;
  
  var som;
  
  if (select == "+") {
    var som = getal1 + getal2;
  }
  
  if (getal3 == som) {
    uitkomst.style.color = "green";
  } else {
    uitkomst.style.color = "red";
  }

  uitkomst.innerHTML = "The calculation " + getal1 + " " + select + " " + getal2 + " = " + som;
}
```

```css
h3 {
  color: green;
}

#uitkomst {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<pre>
         <h2>Javascript Calculator</h2>
         Insert first number:   <input type="number" id="getal_1">

         Insert second number:  <input type="number" id="getal_2">
        
         My own calculation:    <input type="number" id="getal_3">
         
         Operation:             <select id="operation">
                    <option value="+">Plus</option>
                    <option value="-">Minus</option>
                    <option value="/">Divide</option>
                    <option value="*">Multiply</option>
                                 </select>

         <h3 id="uitkomst" >The answer is:</h3>

         <button id="button">Calculate</button>
      </pre>
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks a lot for your help! I copied and run the code you send, but the only thing is, the calculator doesn't function for some reason.. I don't know if you would like to take a quick look at the code again? I would really appreciate it, since the deadline for this project is in about 8 hours. Thanks :)